# How can I feed variable number of images to a Tensorflow TimeDistributed Layer?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to perform image classification using a CNN with a EfficientNet Backbone using Tensorflow. The original image is very large and contains a significant amount of whitespace. Therefore, it has been split into tiles. For example, the first image has 30 tiles (also known as patches). Each patch is 256 x 256 in size.
[image: Visual representation of tiling method]However, not all images have exactly 30 tiles. Some have significantly more while some have significantly less. All tiles are important. I am intending upon exploring the usage of LSTMs (TimeDistributed Layers) for this dataset to handle variable input. The data produced through the Tensorflow Dataset takes the shape of: (None, 256, 256, 3). The None is due to the fact that the number of patches / tiles varies and the last 3 dimensions is explained by the fact that each tile takes the shape of (256, 256, 3) as it is 256 x 256.

Given that the Tensorflow Dataset produces output of (None, 256, 256, 3), I assumed this would be the input as well. However, [Tensorflow's model `input_shape` is limited to 3 input channels](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/efficientnet_v2/EfficientNetV2B0). Therefore, I set `input_shape` to be `(256, 256, 3)` as shown below:

```
B0 = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2B0(
    weights='imagenet',
    include_top=False,
    pooling='avg',
    input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
)
```

In another example that utilized the same dataset that I am utilizing, [an individual also utilized TimeDistributed Layers](https://www.kaggle.com/code/vgarshin/panda-keras-timedistributed/notebook), but as he always had 10 tiles per image, he utilized the following:

```
bottleneck = efn.EfficientNetB1(
    weights='../input/effnetweights/efficientnet-b1_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_autoaugment_notop.h5', 
    include_top=False, 
    pooling='avg'
)
bottleneck = Model(inputs=bottleneck.inputs, outputs=bottleneck.layers[-2].output)
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(bottleneck, input_shape=(SEQ_LEN, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)))
```

where SEQ_LEN is 10, IMG_SIZE is 120.
While this example, uses 10 tiles per image and is static, articles on the internet show that [Tensorflow's TimeDistributed Wrapper allows the handling of variable length input](https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-network-for-input-of-variable-length-using-tensorflow-timedistributed-wrapper-a45972f4da51) which I interpret to be (variable length amount of tiles).

I therefore attempted to use following as my model:

```
B0 = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet_v2.EfficientNetV2B0(
    weights='imagenet',
    include_top=False,
    pooling='avg',
    input_shape=(TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, 3),
)
B0 = Model(inputs=B0.inputs, outputs=B0.layers[-2].output)
model = Sequential()
model.add(TimeDistributed(B0, input_shape=(None, TILE_SIZE, TILE_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling3D())

model.add(Dense(6, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=Adam(),
    metrics=['categorical_accuracy', tfa.metrics.CohenKappa(num_classes=6, sparse_labels=False, weightage="quadratic")]
)
```

This didn't work and produced the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, None, 256, 256, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, None, 256, 256, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='time_distributed_input'), name='time_distributed_input', description="created by layer 'time_distributed_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, None, None, None).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tom50\OneDrive - Flinders\Honours\TimeDistributed\Main.py", line 59, in <module>
    history = model.fit(
  File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Local\Temp\__autograph_generated_filekcf5gc2z.py", line 15, in tf__train_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 993, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\tom50\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 232, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" "                 f"(type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "time_distributed" is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, None, None, None)
    
    Call arguments received by layer "sequential" "                 f"(type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, None, None, None), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Comment: can you please explain what's the purpose of lstm layer before cnn for image classification ?

Comment: TimeDistributed is almost work as a dense layer with timestamp after LSTM (or any RNN) ... usually for many outputs (1:N or M:N ) can't understand your model actually. is that a full code ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from efficientnet.tfkeras import EfficientNetB0

# Define the input shape and number of classes
input_shape = (256, 256, 3)
num_classes = 5

# Create the model with the EfficientNetB0 backbone
model = keras.Sequential([
    EfficientNetB0(include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape),
    layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Split the image into tiles
def split_image(image, tile_size=(256, 256)):
    tiles = []
    h, w = image.shape[:2]
    for i in range(0, h, tile_size[0]):
        for j in range(0, w, tile_size[1]):
            tiles.append(image[i:i+tile_size[0], j:j+tile_size[1]])
    return tiles

# Load the image
img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img("image.jpg")
img = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
tiles = split_image(img)

# Predict the class of each tile
predictions = []
for tile in tiles:
    x = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(tile)
    x = keras.applications.mobilenet_v2.preprocess_input(x)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    prediction = model.predict(x)
    predictions.append(prediction)
```

This code first creates a model with the EfficientNetB0 backbone and compiles it. Then it loads the image and splits it into tiles using the split_image() function. Finally, it iterates through each tile and uses the model to predict its class.

Please note that this is just a sample and you should modify the code according to your requirement, also note that this code is not tested, so there may be some errors.